# Importing JS from one site to another

Tags: javascript

I created a script that asks you about the difficulty that you want of the game (and a cheat. I realize this isn't a secure way to add a cheat, but that's not the point). I want to save it on another section of my site, and have done so with the import method. I cannot get it to work. How would I export the function `getDiff` from `http://www.willmargulies.com/password.htm` and run it?

```js
import{getDiff} from 'http://www.willmargulies.com/password.htm'
getDiff();
```

Comment: If you're on a DOM you can add it in a source tag, otherwise you're going to have to get the raw string with AJAX and eval it

Comment: You're trying to import from an HTML file. As far as I know, you can only import from a JavaScript module file. I would expect the importer to immediately exception if reading an HTML file since it likely wouldn't be valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The other file needs to:

1. Be a javascript file
2. Have a line somewhat like:

   `export function getDiff() {
    };`

Comment: Probably have to worry about CORS too if this isn't same domain.

Comment: The file type is now set to JavaScript and the reference to it has been updated to add the js file extension. the code of the JS file is                 
        export function getDiff(){
alert("works")
      }

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it by `exports.getDiff = () => {};`